# What is the origin of the phrase "The People's Champion"

Tags: phrases, phrase-origin

What is the origin, or at least first use, of the phrase "The People's Champion" or "The People's champ?"

Wikipedia has a [list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_People%27s_Champion) of people nicknamed the People's champion, but no comment on its origin.

This [question](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/42407/why-is-the-rock-called-the-peoples-champ) on movies.stackexchange implies that Muhammed Ali had some sort of claim on the phrase, but no mention of origin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding phrase origins, "first use" is often a hard bar to jump. That is true of 'people's champion' and the very similar 'champion of the people'.

The earliest uses of those phrases that I have found were in [1768](https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?q1=%22champion%22;id=njp.32101037604236;view=1up;seq=20;num=14;start=1;sz=10;page=search) (p. 14, about midway through the last paragraph) and [1690](https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?id=nyp.33433112026343;view=1up;seq=57) (p. 33, second line), respectively.

'People's champion' appears in George Saville Carey's 1768 *Liberty Chastised: or Patriotism in Chains*, a farcical play:

> ...he has once fairly engaged to *liberty's* and the ***people's* champion**....

'Champion of the people' is used in Thomas D'Urfey's 1690 burlesque poem, *Collin's Walk Through London and Westminster*:

> Whilst I the Lump, th'unfinish'd Cripple
>   Prove more the *Champion of the People*;
>   ....